# Android - Problems with logging the start up latency

Tags: android, adb, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I am trying to **log the start up latency of my app**. They way I am doing it is setting the start time of the app on `Application.onCreate` and provide a public method that returns the time.

```
MyApplication extends Application {
    Date startUpTime;
    //Declare variables
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setStartupTime();
        //other initializations
    }

    private void setStartUpTime() {
        startUpTime = new Date();
    }

    public Date getStartUpTime() {
        return startUpTime;
    }
}

MyActivity extends Activity {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        logStartUpLatency();
        //other onStart stuff
    }

    private void logStartUpLatency() {
        Date currentTime = new Date();
        Date startTime = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext().getStartUpTime();
        long latency = currentTime.getTime() - startTIme.getTime();
        Log.d("Start up Latency is ", Long.toString(latency)):

    }
```

This is how I am testing my start up latency:

- adb install myapk
- run the app to get the first start up latency. I can see the latency logged is correct for the first start
- run the app again to test the start latency. The latency logged is correct for the start(or any number of subsequent starts)
- Now I increase my app's version code and name by 1. To simulate an upgrade, I used the command adb install -r myapk.
- Now I run the app again to test the first start latency after upgrade, even though it takes 3 seconds, the latency logged is off the charts.

Does any one know why that might happen?

**Update**

So if I install the apk using "adb install -r myapk", the app isn't going through the `Myapplication.onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I install the apk using "adb install -r myapk", the app isn't going through the Myapplication.onCreate(). So that answers this question. I will ask a separate question on why installing an application using "adb install -r myapk" and then starting myapk doesn't go through MyApplication.onCreate()

Answer (score 10):

I suggest the use of the [`TimingLogger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) class. As per the documentation, you can easily track the elapsed time and even add splits in the process.

This

```
TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger(TAG, "methodA");
// ... do some work A ...
timings.addSplit("work A");
// ... do some work B ...
timings.addSplit("work B");
// ... do some work C ...
timings.addSplit("work C");
timings.dumpToLog();
```

produces

```
D/TAG (3459): methodA: begin
D/TAG (3459): methodA:      9 ms, work A
D/TAG (3459): methodA:      1 ms, work B
D/TAG (3459): methodA:      6 ms, work C
D/TAG (3459): methodA: end, 16 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The latency you are calculating is in milliseconds. [Date#getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the  number of **milliseconds** since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT.

The observed time of 3 seconds is because of the overhead for uninstalling the old and installing the new app build.